# Problems connecting to Skype 2.8 with Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, networking, connection, skype

I have just downloaded Skype and I cannot get it work on my mac.  I am running the newest version 2.8.  Whenever I try to connect I get the error "Cannot connect to Skype.  Please check your network settings and try again".  I currently have my firewall disabled.  I have read through the Skype forums to try to find a solution and I have seen that a few other people have posted the same issue.  The only solution suggested was to deleted a few library files and remove Skype then reinstall, which I have tried twice with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This may be kinda obvious, but are you connected to the internet?

Comment: On a tcpdump, what do you see when you try and connect with skype?

Answer (score 1):

1. System Preferences
2. Security --> Firewall
3. Select "Set access for specific services and applications"
4. Click the "+" button, and add Skype to the list of firewall exceptions.
5. Click the red "x" to close the window.
6. Open Skype and login with your credentials.

Comment: Firewall exceptions, when firewall is disabled?